# How to insert HTML elements in email body

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to apply HTML when a user prepares email with a default template.

I got some basic code online:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
If InStr(LCase(Item.To), "xxx@gmail.com") Then
    prompt$ = "Are You Sure want to send this email to " & Item.To& " ?"
    If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
        Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        Set objOutlookMsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "<html><body><strong>HELLO OUTLOOK</strong></body></html>"
        objOutlookMsg.Display
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When I send, a new message window opens.

I want that HTML to present in the same window, not a new window.

Comment: Can you post complete code? I'm not able to see same error the same error

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: not sure what the question is but this line of code will display before send `objOutlookMsg.Display`  and if you want to send straight away replace display with send

Comment: @Tim can u tell exact code ? please

Comment: `objOutlookMsg.Send`

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The [Item.To Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.To) Returns String list of display names, what you need it [Recipient.Address Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) which will Return a String representing the email address of the Recipient.*

*Also check `If Item.Class <> olMail if not then Exit Sub`*

*Full Example*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

    Dim Rcpt As Recipient
    Dim Prompt As String
        Prompt = "Are You Sure want to send this email to " & Item.To & " ?"

    For Each Rcpt In Item.Recipients
        If InStr(1, Rcpt.AddressEntry, "TEST@gmail.com", vbTextCompare) Then
            If MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, _
                                              "Check Address ") = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If

         Item.HTMLBody = "<html><body><strong>HELLO OUTLOOK</strong></body></html>" _
                                                                      & Item.HTMLBody
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*Updated per comments*

*Simply remove `if MsgBox end if` block of code*

*Example*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

    Dim Rcpt As Recipient

    For Each Rcpt In Item.Recipients
        If InStr(1, Rcpt.AddressEntry, "TEST@gmail.com", vbTextCompare) Then

         Item.HTMLBody = "<html><body><strong>HELLO OUTLOOK</strong></body></html>" _
                                                                      & Item.HTMLBody
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: good answer bro its working good as i expected, since its for test case i have added alert but i dont want prompt message when i click send in outlook its should send with some HTMl content append over the body, can u please update your answer ?

Comment: the same way we can inject javascript code into body ? so when user open the mail can we idientify whether the recipient read our mail or not ?

Comment: I'm not sure or have not tried, give it try and let me know I'm here to help- post new question with your code and the errors and I will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the HTML body of the message begin sent (it is passed as the Item parameter to your event handler), why are you creating a new message instead of modifying the existing message? Set HTMLBody property on the Item object.